# convert negative hex to text (used in a css file)

Tags: css, hex

hi everyone I want convert a css with HEX to normall text...

some of them I convert them with an [online convertor.](http://hex.online-toolz.com/tools/text-hex-convertor.php)

for example `/39`   --->  `9`

but I saw some negative  Hex from `\-1u` until `\-11u`  ...

the convertor couldn't convert them. how can I convert it to normal text?

Comment: What result do you expect? Hexadecimal codes for ASCII (and Unicode) are always positive.

Comment: but it used in a valid css file! so what is that?

Comment: Can you post the file here so we know the context?